# Exception block for multi-tiered internal system

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library, elmah, error-logging

My project is pretty large it includes IIS servers and Windows Services, even some UNIX/cgi services as well which will be read with WCF framework

It will include 3 layers, an Ms MVC website, Multiple Service gateways, etc..

I am wondering which Exception handling mechanism you would recommend for me.

I am looking for something versatile, but we don't want to go overboard. I checked out ELMAH

From what I understand ELMAH uses HttpModules so it won't work with my Windows services without tweaking it a bit.

Do you recommend something else?

p.s.
I do not have security issues between the layers. They are all in my domain

Comment: Could you define "exception handling mechanism" please? ELMAH and log4net mentioned below are both logging solutions, not exception handling; you'll still need to write code to catch exceptions and log them. What do you want this mechanism to do for you?

Comment: We are looking at Exception Block such as (Enterprise Library blocks) EL 5. we will be using EntityFramework under MVC and in other data areas.
I just feel the EL may be too complex for us, and maybe tweeking ELMAH to accept windows services exceptions would be the better way to go. We will have custom exceptions, but all the rewrapping and security removal is more than we require for our project. which don't get me wrong is very large. will include of 10 service modules each with its own datacenter and service locator.

Comment: Let me rephrase: what do you want this exception handling mechanism to actually *do*? What use case are you trying to satisfy? Is it just "log my exceptions", or do you need centralized exception shielding, wrapping, transformation, etc?

Comment: I know a great deal about different Exception Blocks theoretically and usage-wise with amdocs enterprise solutions. I am in a new project looking to implement some exception blocks. I am considering rule based because down the line, im quite sure we will come up with requirements we are unfamiliar with. However, as of right now, we have no special cases (although this is the first sprint, and we all know how that goes). I am considering EL vs ELMAH. I am leaning toward ELMAH, so i guess We will need to create some flavor of ELMAH that plugs into Windows services.or use a MAMOTH EL. wwjd ? :P

Answer (score 1):

Use log4net. To make it more robust you need to create another WCF service that just logs your exception, error or messages into your database.

Steps for that.

1 - Modify client application's web.config / app.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

2 - Add log4net section as below.

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="WcfAppender" type="Problem.Common.Logging.WcfAppender, Problem.Common">
      <endpointAddress value="http://localhost.poc.trunk.site-dev.local/Services/Log.svc"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="log.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <target value="Console.Error" />
      <mapping>
        <level value="FATAL" />
        <foreColor value="Red" />
        <backColor value="White" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Cyan" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <foreColor value="Green" />
      </mapping>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>
    <logger name="WcfLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="WcfAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="FileLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

3 - Create log.svc as mentioned below.

```
namespace Problem.CustomerCore.Services
{
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Common.ExceptionHandling;
using log4net;
using log4net.Core;

/// <summary>
/// Service contract for instrumentation operations - such as logging and performance tracking
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILogPOC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes an entry to the logging framework
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logDateTime">The timestamp that the event occurred</param>
    /// <param name="logLevel">The level of the event</param>
    /// <param name="host">The host on which the event occurred</param>
    /// <param name="loggerName">The name of the type that originally raised the exception</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message describing the event context</param>
    /// <param name="exception">Excpetion object in case of the log entry being an error</param>
    /// <param name="version">The version number of the component reporting the log entry</param>
    /// <param name="tenancyExternalReference">The external reference identifying the current tenancy.</param>
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ProcessingResultsList))]
    void WriteLogEntry(DateTime logDateTime, Level logLevel, string host, string loggerName, string message, string exception, string version, Guid tenancyExternalReference);
}

/// <summary>
/// Methods for instrumenting the application
/// </summary>
public class Log : ILogPOC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The logger to use for writing out exceptions nad info logs
    /// </summary>
    private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Instrumentation));

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes an entry to the logging framework
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logDateTime">The timestamp that the event occurred</param>
    /// <param name="logLevel">The level of the event</param>
    /// <param name="host">The host on which the event occurred</param>
    /// <param name="loggerName">The name of the type that originally raised the exception</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message describing the event context</param>
    /// <param name="exception">Excpetion object in case of the log entry being an error</param>
    /// <param name="version">The version number of the component reporting the log entry</param>
    /// <param name="tenancyExternalReference">The external reference identifying the current tenancy.</param>
    public void WriteLogEntry(DateTime logDateTime, Level logLevel, string host, string loggerName, string message, string exception, string version, Guid tenancyExternalReference)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        ThreadContext.Properties["Host"] = host;
        ThreadContext.Properties["Version"] = version;
        ThreadContext.Properties["Tenancy"] = tenancyExternalReference;
        ThreadContext.Properties["User"] = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

        var eventData = new LoggingEventData
                            {
                                Identity = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name,
                                UserName = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name,
                                Level = logLevel,
                                LoggerName = loggerName,
                                TimeStamp = logDateTime,
                                Message = message,
                                ExceptionString = exception
                            };
        var logEvent = new LoggingEvent(eventData);

        // log the exception
        logger.Logger.Log(logEvent);
    }
}
}
```

4 - Create a log table into the database as well.

5 - Web.config for WCF should look like this. especially log4net section.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.30319.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <lossy value="true" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="INFO"/>
      </evaluator>
      <connectionString value="Database=XYZ-trunk;Server=localhost;User ID=a;Password=b;Trusted_Connection=False;" />
      <connectionStringName value="connectionException" /> 
      <commandText value="[dbo].[spLog_WriteEntry]" />
      <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@LogDateTime" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" /> 
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Component" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@LogLevel" /> 
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Host" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{Host}"/>
        </layout> 
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Message" /> 
        <dbType value="String" /> 
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Coulmn1" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{Tenancy}"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Username" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{User}"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
       <threshold value="WARN"/>
       <to value="error@a.com" />
       <from value="build@abc.com" />
       <subject value="SmtpAppender" />
       <smtpHost value="xyz.com" />
       <bufferSize value="512" />
       <lossy value="false" />
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
       </layout>
    </appender>
    <root> 
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Now you setup your WCF service.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Tuzo, thank you for your suggestion. I am less of an NIH person, but this was something we were considering. I will definately take this into serious consideration, and at least create a test project to check this out. although this is a Logger, not an exception handler or event listener. but thank you for the verbose explanation. :)